Export unreal engine landscape as 3d model into blender
I am trying to export my unreal engine 5 landscape map into blender and while the model seems to export and import properly, the textures on the other hand do not show up in blender leaving me with a shiny dark model with no color. I know that it seems to work with exporting meshes but when it comes to a whole landscape it does not seem to work as I would expect. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
